# How do you capture the date and time when a user clicks the submit button? Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, express, web

I have an html file with an onRegisterSubmit() function to submit a form.
My register.ts file looks like this... it adds the user from the submitted form in html and validates and authenticates the user.

```
    onRegisterSubmit(){

    const user = {
        name: this.name,
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }

    //calling the validate service validate register function
    //If the forms are not all filled
    if(!this.validateService.validateRegister(user)){

        //using flash messages
        this.flashMessage.show('Please fill in all fields', {cssClass: 
        'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});

        return false;

    }

  //validate email
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)){

        this.flashMessage.show('Please enter a valid email', {cssClass: 
        'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});

        return false;

    }

  //register User/ talks to authservice/ Since its an observable, we have to 
  //subscribe to it
  //Data is the return info received in users.js
  this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {

     //Receive a true or false based on the add user function in users.js 
     if(data.success){

       this.flashMessage.show('You are now Registered', {cssClass: 'alert-
        success', timeout: 3000});

       //This will navigate to log in route because registration success
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);

     } else {

       this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-
       danger', timeout: 3000});
       this.router.navigate(['/register']);
     }
  })

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Date Object :

`var date = new Date();`

MDN documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: do i have to import anything to use Date() function?

Comment: No it's a basic function of JS